# How to programatically create a LinkedIn Group Discussion?

Tags: php, linkedin-api, modx-evolution

I wish to interact with the LinkedIn Groups API in order to programatically add content to my group page using PHP. The typical flow would be:

1. Detect when a new item is posted on my website by the CMS
2. Extract Title, Description and the URL of the news item
3. Authenticate with LinkedIn API
4. Create a new discussion thread in my LinkedIn group (using info from step 2)

I am using MODx as a CMS and can easily code step 1 and 2. As for the LinkedIn part I am at a loss. Using search (Google & SO) I've only come across incomplete code fragments with little or no explanation.

Using a third party app like LinksAlpha would be acceptable. However they only offer a WordPress plugin. Sadly documentation to adapt to a different CMS is insufficient.

Comment: Please supply a reason for downvoting

Comment: Whilst not the downvoter, the tooltip for the downvote implies usage is when "The question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I suspect someone deemed that there is no research evident in your question.

Comment: Everyone is entitled to their opinion. The documentation on this is really scarce and the question is valid however.

Answer (score 1):

Linked In uses OAuth as a means of authentication, and they go over [the steps in a reasonable level of detail in their documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

There is an example of [how to create a group discussion](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#create) on the Linked In API documentation. Essentially, you POST to `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/{group-id}/posts` XML describing the new post, of the form:

```
<post>
  <title>New Group Discussion</title>
  <summary>What does everyone think about platform development?</summary>
  <content>
    <submitted-url>http://developer.linkedin.com</submitted-url>
    <title>Build the Professional Web with LinkedIn</title>
    <description>A great resource for finding documentation and answers related to developing on the LinkedIn Platform</description>
  </content>
</post>
```

Comment: I've already seen that LinkedIn doc and it is *extremely* limited. It misses how to actually send the request by PHP or otherwise. Also there is no mention of what response can be expected and what to make of it (error codes or success).